# Why i get 0? must be a word

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

[image]

Why checkbox has 0? 
There must be string "Avatar" from string resourse.
I need help.
Here's my code..................
................................
................................

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/no_avatar"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="jjjjj"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkbox"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:height="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:checked="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="9dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fill ListView from SQLite

```
try{
        SQLiteOpenHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(v.getContext());
        db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query("PEOPLE", new String[] {"_id", "NAME", "CHECKBOX"}, null, null, null, null, null);
        CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[]{"NAME", "CHECKBOX"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.checkBox}, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    } 
    catch (SQLiteException e){
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "База данных недоступна", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The resources file:

```
<resources> 
    <string name="app_name">Test Application</string> 
    <!-- TODO: Remove or change this placeholder text --> 
    <string name="menu_lang">English</string> 
    <string name="listtab">List</string> 
    <string name="scalingtab">Scaling</string> 
    <string name="parsingtab">Parsing</string> 
    <string name="maptab">Map</string> 
    <string name="checkbox">Avatar</string> 
    <string name="btn_add">Add</string> 
    <string name="btn_rev">Revert</string> 
    <string name="add_title">Add new person</string> 
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting "0" instead of "Avatar" because the `SimpleCursorAdapter` treats the `CheckBox` as a kind of `TextView` (which is basically correct because `CheckBox` is an indirect subclass of `TextView`).

For all `TextView`s, it will simply set the text to the value ("0" or "1") from the corresponding database column (**CHECKBOX**).

If you want a different behaviour, your `Activity` (or `Fragment`) has to act as a `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder
```

You set the `Activity` as `ViewBinder` for the `SimpleCursorAdapter` like this:

```
CursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(v.getContext(), R.layout.list_item, cursor, new String[]{"NAME", "CHECKBOX"}, new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.checkBox}, 0);
listAdapter.setViewBinder(this);
```

You have to override the `setViewValue()` method:

```
@Override
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex)
{
    if (view instanceof CheckBox)
    {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)view;
        String checked = cursor.getString(columnindex);
        switch(checked)
        {
             case "0":
                 cb.setChecked(false);
                 break;
             default: // <=> case "1"
                 cb.setChecked(true);
        }

        // ('true' means you took care of it )
        return true;
    }

    // don't do anything with other View types as the default worked fine
    // ('false' means you leave it to the SimpleCursorAdapter)
    return false;
}
```

Comment: setViewBinder is red.

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi - did you write something like " MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder"  and did you also override `setViewValue()` in the activity code like I suggested?

Comment: @EvgenyGooDi - and one other thing: it wasn't clear from your question whether you use an `Activity`or a `Fragment`. If you are using a `Fragment` then the Fragment should implement `SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder`, not the `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

0 is the current value of your "checkbox" string contained in the res/values/string.xml file

If you don't want to display a text on your checkbox remove `android:text="@string/checkbox"`

Comment: Its true. In database i save 0 or 1 for checked/unchecked checkbox. I dont need to see this number, i need restore right view of checkbox. Well, i done wrong my job ((

Comment: So remove the  android:text="@string/checkbox" attribute on your checkbox

Comment: Can you share your string resource?